# Generating function for $\sum{\sqrt{n^2+n}x^na_n}$ if $\sum x^{n+1}a_{n+1} = A(x)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I am looking for a a simplification for $\sum{\sqrt{n^2+n}x^na_n}$ if $\sum x^{n+1}a_{n+1} = A(x)$ (summing over $n$). A problem that uses something similar to this is in Generatingfunctionology and I am trying to get a more general solution.

Comment: Asking for "simplification" without context doesn't mean anything. What is your concrete problem ?.. If $f(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n,  g(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0} b_n z^n$ then $\sum_{n \ge 0} a_n b_n z^n = \frac{1}{2i \pi}\int_{|s| = r} f(z/s) g(s)\frac{ds}{s}$

Comment: Can I write it without the sum in terms of $A(x)$